# linux scheduling to strictly prefer higher priority thread than low priority thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have a main thread M and several worker threads W1, W2, ..., Wn, where N is a number of cores - 1. A main thread M has default priority and worker threads have nice value of 5 + i/N * 15. For example, when N = 4, workers will have nice 5, 10, 15, 20.

When only one process is running, each of all threads (one main and 4 workers) nicely occupies one core and utilize 100%; thus adding up to 500%.

When multiple, e.g. 2, processes are running, all threads of two processes nicely share cpu utilization. Main threads take 100%, and worker threads takes about 50%, 40%, 10%, 5%; all sums up to about 600%.

This is certainly an expected behavior on default scheduling, yet I want to change this behavior to strictly prefer higher priority worker than lower priority worker. Since worker threads' local variables are quite big, I want higher priority workers to run whenever possible and reuse them. That is, a desired behavior are 100% of main, 100% of worker 1, 100% of worker 2, 20% (or something between 0~100%) of worker 3, 0% of worker 4, etc..., when 3 cores are available.

I believe that I need to change scheduling policy, probably something other than SCHED_RR. Without affecting other jobs, what policy would be best for this process?

Comment: What's wrong with using SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR for this purpose?

Comment: Well, both SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR still schedule low priority threads to run when high priority threads are idle. The desirable behavior is to always run higher one: When high is running, low can run. When high is not running, low can't run.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent a low priority thread from running when the high priority threads are idle?  A CPU with nothing running on it is a wasted resource.  Having the low priority thread run when the high priority thread is idle does not harm the high priority thread in any way, because as soon as the high priority thread is ready to run again, it will kick the low priority thread off of the CPU and run.

Comment: Normally, your point is right; it doesn't harm. However, in my specific usage, worker threads require a quite expensive operations to initialize/finalize (mostly associated with external libraries and memory allocation). Thus, unless there is an certainty that low priority thread will get enough cpu utilization, high priority thread should acquire cpu to reuse already allocated resources. That is; instead of W1 50% and W2 20%, W1 70% and W2 0% is much better. I was thinking to dynamically create W2 only if W1 is utilizing enough CPU, but detecting cpu usage isn't an easy task either...

Comment: I think the proper solution there is to do the expensive initialize operations only once, at process start, rather than over and over again; e.g. use a thread pool with persistent low-priority threads rather than constantly spawning new threads.  Trying to play games with the scheduler is probably not going to lead you to a useful result, since in general there is no way to know in advance how much CPU a low-priority thread is going to get in the future.